# How to close binance future position for all open orders via api

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I am unable to close the open positions like BINANCE future interface did. Can anyone guide me that I am right path. Currently I am try to close the positions using create orders api with below parameters. I have 2 sale orders in open positions and I want close them. I trying to implement same behavior as BINANCE future close all position did.

```
Binance.futures_create_order(symbol=self.symbol, side=‘BUY’, type=‘Limit’,closePosition=true)
```

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

info = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side='BUY', type='STOP_MARKET',stopPrice='30000',closePosition=True)

print(info)

you can go like this to get stop loss for your open position _stop price in required